# Изменить формат input date

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Как изменить формат даты в `input[type='date']`. Сервер совершает проверку по регулярному выражению, т.е. в итоге значение должно быть `dd-mm-yyyy`. По умолчанию подставляется в формате `yyyy-mm-dd`. Менять код на сервере нельзя, ибо вызовет множество конфликтов

Comment: Никак. Добавьте скрытый input, в который на onchange  записывайте значение dateInput.value.replace(/(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)/,'$3-$2-$1')

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Добавьте скрытый input, в который на onchange записывайте значение dateInput.value.replace(/(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)/,'$3-$2-$1')

```js
$('input[type="date"]').on('input change',function() {
  $(this).next().val(this.value.replace(/(\d*)-(\d*)-(\d*)/, '$3-$2-$1'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" value="2014-02-09">
<input name="date" value="09-02-2014" должен_быть_hidden>
```

Comment: Как вариант, единственное поле можно подменять при отправке на сервер. А потом обратно.